# Thunar does not automount USB drives anymore

Tags: usb, automount, thunar

Automounting USB drives used to work fine. I do not know what I changed to make it stop working.
The user account still has all groups configured, the media manager still shows the automount enabled marks.

I now get "Not authorized to perform operation." when trying to open the drive. Thunar still shows the drawer. "Send to" menu also does not work.

I can mount as root by hand but I want to repair the old behavior.
I have issues with USB sticks will all sorts of file systems, none are mounting automatic (FAT32, XFS, NTFS which all did work before)

I am using Xubuntu 18.04 and also tried updating all packages.

Comment: While browsing through tons of forum threads with answers or reports of a similar problem I found this.

If I run  /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
automounting magically starts working again, e.q. if run this in a terminal and then plugin some USB key, it mounts as intended.

I am sure this program is not meant to be run by hand. 

How to get it run in the right spot again?

Comment: Deleteing $HOME/.config/ also didn't help but even after unpacking a backup I still lost other configurations. Not too much of a deal, the problem is still not solved.